# Redirecting Hebrew and Aramaic Language

Tags: discussion, hebrew, area51

Although I don't have the exact numbers, I can tell you that I've seen a bunch of Hebrew, non-Jewish-related questions that have been closed for said reason. Hebrew is an open proposal on Area 51, and so, if you'd like to have a place to post Hebrew-related questions, I'd like to direct everyone to [Hebrew Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102005/hebrew-language?referrer=i15I63pGVH3z9iP5rZSXOw2). The proposal has been restarted, so let's see if we can get enough support over there to get the site up and running. There is also the [Aramaic Language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101779/aramaic-language?referrer=i15I63pGVH3r6vz5tFoudg2) proposal, that we can also send some support over to.

Comment: The proposal we're advertising has now died and been restarted; how do folks feel about swapping in the new link for the ad we already have?  (Well, had -- it won't be served because the old A51 image is now dead.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Naturally, *I'd* like it. :P

Comment: I updated the ad, because the image in the old one was broken yet the ad was still being served (I saw that broken image on main).  I trust that people who voted to advertise the site in commitment would also vote to advertise the new site in definition, but if not, the edit allows vote changes.

Comment: Aramaic language has been deleted!

Comment: @einpoklum I posted this back in 2016; clearly there’s not enough support for these Area 51 proposals, as since then there’s been a catch-all “Semitic Languages” proposal and even that failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, it would be great if a Hebrew Stack Exchange community could be created. Note that Mi Yodeya already promotes this Area 51 proposal via a ["community promotion ad"](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3857/2).

Answer (score 2):

The old 'Hebrew Language' proposal has died. I have restarted it.

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Hebrew Language]

Comment: ... and now it's dead again.